# Prove that a function analytic on an open set in C with bounded coefficients is entire

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)=\sum_{n\geq 0}a_n z^n$ for $z\in D(0,1)$ and $|n!a_n|\leq M$ for all $n\geq 0$ and for some $M\geq 0$. Prove that $f$ is entire.

I feel that this question is missing some hypothesis. Perhaps $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{C}$?

**Edit**: I was trying to ask a modified version of another question, but I made a simple mistake. The hypothesis is supposed to read $|n!a_n|\leq M$. In this case, I feel like this is an easy problem, but I'll ask again if I get stuck.

Comment: There's definitely a hypothesis missing. What about $a_n = 1$ for all $n$, for example?

Comment: There's actually a stronger bound on the coefficients than I realized. I edited it to reflect this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed something is missing. You should ask something stronger on the coefficients of the power series.

In particular the following must hold true:
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left( a_n^{1/n}\right) = 0
\end{equation}
In this case, the radius of convergence of the power series is infinite and the power series defines an entire function.

**Edit:** if $|n!a_n| \leq M$, then the equation above holds true.

Comment: This answers to your edited post. If the stronger hypotesis on the coefficients holds, then the limit above exists and is equal to zero.

Comment: Yup, I realized this. My troubles with this question came from an improper deduction of facts. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Accept it and vote it up then :)